emacs M-x & shortcuts
I have been using emacs extensively on Linux for decades now, but could never get shortcuts to work, and never bothered with it.
However now, since I get autosave data due to my recent setup, I need to know how to use the M-x shortcut.
M-x means nothing and doesnt work.
I read online that it actually means the escape key (go figure)
Just once I got an M-x prompt using the escape key. Could not repeat it again, but I should be able to after infinite retries.
Question: What do I type at the M-x prompt to get recovery data updated? This is primarily related to gui-emacs interface.

The question isn't clear. Be sure you're starting Emacs using emacs -Q (no init file), then give a step-by-step recipe to reproduce what you're trying or asking about, saying at each step what you did, what you saw, and what you expected to see instead. Thx.

What do you mean by "recovery data"? Recovery from what? Who produced them? Why/how are the recovery data updated? What do you mean by "shortcuts"? Your question is bafflingly unclear.

M-x means to hold down the Meta key and type x. Of course, most keyboards these days don’t actually have a Meta key, so Emacs generally expects Alt instead.
And yes, because of the way the old–school teletypes worked, M-x was encoded on the wire as an escape character followed by an “x”. You can literally hit the escape key and then type an “x” to replicate this. This means that when Emacs is running inside of a terminal, the terminal emulator translates A-x into ESC x, and then Emacs translates it back to M-x. For compatibility the Emacs GUI also listens for ESC x and translates it to M-x, so typing ESC x will also work in the GUI.
That bit about “recovery data” appears to be a second question. You should limit yourself to one question at a time, so that the answers are nicely categorized for future visitors.
Edit:
It appears, from your comments, that none of us have understood your question. You said

I need to know how to use the M-x shortcut. M-x means nothing and doesnt work. […] Just once I got an M-x prompt using the escape key.

This means to me that you want to know how to type M-x, which I answered above. You seem to know that once you do type M-x successfully, you will get a prompt, and that you can type the name of any command at that prompt to execute it. Do let us know if you can type M-x and get the prompt reliably, because if you cannot do this even though you have used Emacs for “decades” then you are operating with a rather severe handicap. Possibly literally, and not just in the golf sense.

What do I type at the M-x prompt to get recovery data updated?

This seems to be your second question. You want to know the name of a particular command, one that updates some recovery data. No one here has any clue what you mean by that. Are you using some package? What setup have you done recently? If you can tell us these things, it may clear everything up.

No need. Recovery of data is reported by emacs to be activated by M-x, therefore the same question as they are intimately related.
Most importantly, read my question. It is still unanswered.

Where is it "reported by emacs to be activated by M-x"? M-x by itself does not do anything: it waits for you to type a command so that it can execute it (M-x is bound to the function execute-extended-command).
